# How do I programmatically check if a secondary ip service range is in use by a GKE cluster?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-vpc

I pre-create secondary ranges for my GKE clusters to use.

How do I programmatically check if a secondary range is currently in use by a cluster or is free?

I use the python API.

I can't even see how to list secondary ranges in a VPC. Looking at the docs the only thing I see remotely related to VPC is for VPC access connectors:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The VPC components are part of the **google-cloud-compute** you should check the [SubnetworksClient](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.services.subnetworks.SubnetworksClient)

The SubnetworkSecondaryRange is an attribute of the class [Subnetwork](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/compute/latest/google.cloud.compute_v1.types.Subnetwork)

[image]

There is no flag "use" in the secondary ranges because the secondary ranges can be used in more than one cluster, because of that you need to implement some logic to loop through all the clusters and check for the secondary ranges in use.

Comment: Secondary service ranges cannot be used in more than one cluster. There is no metadata attached to the ranges that say if they are in use?

Comment: Hi @red888 "You can share the primary range, secondary IP address range for Pods, and secondary IP address range for Services between clusters in the same subnetwork. This behavior is available for both Standard and Autopilot clusters." https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alias-ips#sharing_ip_address

Comment: Is this new? Does shared VPC support this? I swear I literally just read in the docs service ranges cannot be shared across multiple GKE clusters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67372142/can-you-share-pod-and-service-secondary-ip-range-between-gke-clusters

Comment: Yes, I am using with Shared VPC